# How to create firestore security rule with nested get() calls?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following firestore database (simplified)

```
groups
  group1
    role=guest
  group2
    role=user
  group3
    role=moderator
users
  user1
    group=group1
  user2
    group=group2
items
  item1
  item2
```

Let's say I want to only allow users to read `/items` data.
Here's my approach:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

            function getUser(id) {
                return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(id)).data
            }

            function getGroup(id) {
                return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(id)).data
            }

            function getRole(id) {
                return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(id)).data
            }

            match /items/{document=**} {
                allow read: if getRole(getGroup(getUser(request.auth.id).group).role) == 'user'
            }

    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Looks like it is not possible to do nested calls in firestore rules.
I tested `getGroup()` with hardcoded id and it works fine:

```
allow read: if getGroup('<userGroupId>') == 'user'
```

This also works:

```
allow read: if getUser(request.auth.uid).group == '<userGroupId>'
```

But it fails on this more complex rule:

```
allow read: if getGroup(getUser(request.auth.uid).group) == 'user'
```

Is it possible to make it work?
Is there another way to do this if not?

Comment: Does it just not work in the simulator, or do these rules also not work as expected when fully deployed?  Sometimes the simulator fails when full deployment works.

Comment: Looks like you're right, Doug!
I struggled to make it work in the simulator, but it works just fine when deployed.

Comment: pff have been trying to make this work for hours with no success